# Email finder(web)

Tags: python, email

This app will run on a website and find all emails and return them.

```
def testEmails(url):
    'Test the emails() function'
    email = ''
    content = urlopen(url).read().decode()
    pattern='[A-Za-z0-9_.]+\@[A-Za-z0-9_.]+\.'
    for attr in content:
        if attr[0] == 'href':
           print(attr)
           email+='{} '.format(attr)
    emails = re.findall(pattern,email)
    return emails
```

I keep getting a blank string anyone know why?

EDIT:

this is my current code:

```
def emails(content):
'return list of email addresses contained in string content'
    email = []
    content = urlopen(url).read().decode()
    pattern='[A-Za-z0-9_.]+\@[A-Za-z0-9_.]+\....'
    email.append(re.findall(pattern,content))
    print(email)
```

but for some reason i get:

```
[['somePERSON@university.ca"']]
```

instead of :

```
['somePERSON@university.ca']
```

Answer (score 2):

`urlopen().read().decode()` returns a unicode string.  So looping through it loops through indivudual characters.  Not the HTML attributes you're looking for.  You should either use HTMLParser to extract attributes, or run re.findall on the entire document (cruder, but would also extract email addresses in plaintext).

Comment: Ya, i was trying to avoid the whole extracting from the whole thing, but if there is no other way with what i have...